# How to add ellipsis inUITextView by the use of UITextPosition?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uitextposition

Is it possible to calculate the number of Visible characters in UITextView?there is possibility that the text in textview may be more or less than the size of UITextView..so I just want to truncate the last 3 visible characters and add ellipsis..
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using [UITextView Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) -

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

here you can check for size and truncate the text.

But i don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: I am getting data after parsing than displayed in UITextView..I cant use this delegate..

Comment: ohh.. you are using UITextField for display instead of user input. Why not UILabel ? Anyway, when you setting text of UItextView, at that time you can truncate it.

Comment: no,i am using UITextView..firstly parsing is done and than display data in uitextview..during parsing I can get less or more data than size of UITextView..so when display , i want to show textview contain data and ellipsis both.